# File I/O in C,unable to delete the previously written data

Tags: c

I want to delete the previously written data on a text file where i want to write my new data.How it can be done.I am able to write a data in a file but unable to delete the previously written content.Need help

Comment: Post the code that you have so far. Also, do you want to completely replace the file content or just the last write(s)?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file in write mode then it will overwrite any existing contents, e.g.

```
FILE * f = fopen("foo.txt", "w"); // open file - may already exist and contain text
fprintf(f, "Hello world\n");      // write new contents
fclose(f);                        // file foo.txt now contains "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file as write only (not append, only write) and write there your new data.
The old data will be removed.